# Regex Replace %20 with Hyphen and remove file extension from URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, redirect

I have this Regex:

```
(\s(?=(?:(?!\/)[^\/])*(\.htm)$))
```

which replace all the white spaces after the last forward slash and before the file extension.

This works on URL like:

```
http://example.com/someFolder/someSubfolder/some Sub Folder/00-02 File with whitespaces.htm
```

It gives:

```
http://example.com/someFolder/someSubfolder/some Sub Folder/00-02-File-with-whitespaces.htm
```

I need to remove file extension too.

I need exactly this output:

```
http://example.com/someFolder/someSubfolder/some Sub Folder/00-02-File-with-whitespaces
```

How I can do it With .htaccess Rewrite or Redirect? I'm able to do it in .htaccess only for %20 or only removing file extension, but not both together.

Comment: What output do you need exactly?

Comment: No, it is not possible because you replace with different replacements patterns. Use a separate replacement step to remove final `.html` (`/\.html$/` -> ''). However, if you use Boost or PCRE2, you can do that with one regex replacement.

Comment: I have tried in two steps in .htaccess file but it doesn't work. I'm able to do it in .htaccess only for %20 or only removing file extension, but not both together.

Comment: You need two completely different replacement pattern *(as @WiktorStribiżew said)*, you want to replace both all spaces with  dash `-` and replace `.html` with nothing ... That's impossible at one step

Comment: so, I'll edit and change my question